# Why I get error when I try to hit action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I use MVC 4 in my project.

I have an action method that I try to fire with this link:

```
https://localhost/Mobile/Map/Index/5/184614.560225826,666226.8163541115/7/3
```

The signature of the action method in Map controller is:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id = 0, PointF center = new PointF(), int zoom = 0, int rotation = 0)
```

Also, I defined this Permalink route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Permalink",
            url: "Map/Index/id/zoom/rotation"
        );
```

When I try to hit the method above, I get this error on the web page:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

While this link works perfectly:

```
  https://localhost/Mobile/Map/Index/5
```

Any idea why the first link not works?

Comment: try using Route Attribute in your action method ex [Route(“users/{name}”]

Comment: if it doesn't work then try calling like query string param.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Permalink",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{zoom}/{rotation}"
        );

Comment: or try this route.

Comment: @Manish thanks for the post. Should I change the default router or edit the permalink router?

Comment: for now try updating Permalink, if it doesn't work then try to update default one.

Comment: 1. put "Permalink" route on top otherwise it wont be called. 
2. Test it out but goes something like your url line be like "Map/{something} 3.. add your parameter line. [source] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)